# Can AVFoundation Capture Depth using iPhone XR Back Camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

I do not currently have an iPhone XR device to query the `AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession` for available device types on the XR's back facing camera.

Is the iPhone XR back camera a `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInTrueDepthCamera` or is it a `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera` that supports depth capture?

Otherwise, is depth capture only supported for the Native iOS Camera.app?

Thanks!

Comment: This works for XS -

`let videoDeviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes:[.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)`

Not sure how it would perform on XR though because it has only 1 back camera.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the the `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera` on the iPhone XR is actually supports depth capture. So You can configure the device discovery session to return the `.builtInWideAngleCamera` and set `capturePhotoOuptut.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = capturePhotoOutput.isDepthDataSupported`.

Hope this helps, feel free to reach out with any questions.